# git cloneしたディレクトリを複数ユーザで共有できますか？

Tags: git

あるユーザーAが `git clone` したディレクトリをサーバに公開しています。
レポジトリーは、Git organization にはいっています。
ユーザBがOrganizationのOrganizarで、サーバのディレクトリを `git pull` して更新することはできますか？

```
$ sudo git pull
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user_a/stackoverflow.git/'
```

と表示されました。
エラーはパスワードが廃止になったのでその件ですが・・
`uthentication failed for 'https://github.com/user_a/stackoverflow.git/'`
でuser_aとなっていたのが気になりました。

Comment: 「一つのディレクトリを共有する」がどのような状態を指すのか、求める姿を明確にする必要があります。また後半は何を言っているのかわかりません。「その件」などと代名詞を使わず、独立した質問として完結させてください。

Comment: 「git clone したディレクトリをサーバに公開しています」の「サーバ」も何を指しているのか曖昧に感じます。GitHub のリモートリポジトリなのか、それともローカルのデータを何か別の形 (web サーバのコンテンツ等) として公開しているのか etc ... / `sudo` 付きで `git pull` を実行すると、root 権限でコマンドが実行されますが、これもどういった意図なのか読み取れませんでした。

Comment: 質問文には認証エラーが掲載されていますが、ユーザーA および ユーザB はそれぞれ自分のリポジトリの pull / push は可能な状態なのでしょうか？ それができていない場合、他人のリポジトリを操作するのは時期尚早に思います。

Answer (score 1):

"ローカルリポジトリを共有ディレクトリとして複数ユーザーで直接編集したい" ということであれば、不整合が発生する可能性があるので避けた方が無難です。

[ベアリポジトリとノンベアリポジトリ：理論編](https://www.nekotricolor.com/entry/theory-of-bare-and-non-bare-repository-manage-wordpress-themes-with-git)

> Gitにはファイルロック機能がないそうなので、複数人で実ファイルのあるノンベアリポジトリにがしがしコミットすると不整合が起こります。

そもそもリモートリポジトリを使って既に共有はできているのだから、ユーザー毎に各々が管理するローカルリポジトリで作業するのが本来の使い方かと思います。

Comment: この回答は質問を読み違えているように見受けられます。質問はGitHub上のリポジトリを複数人がpull（およびpush）できるか？ 現状pullでエラーになる、というもののように読めます。

Answer (score 0):

(他の方が書かれているように、現在の質問文からは意図を汲み取ることは不可能だと感じましたが、可能性のひとつとして)
下図のような状況で、`ユーザB` が `updated.git` リポジトリの更新を `original.git` リポジトリへ反映したいがどうすれば良いか、という質問だと理解しました。

[image: 配置図]
([plantuml](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/NP4nJa9148RxFSLS00v0OT16xw263Ep0sy2R8VFc1IEXuBt6mif22sFiA2oCXJ4MtcOJpk6g9Anacp_xJUR__qo_CbIhovchfe7dg5X2WUmN6io8mRIc39N2CYfKIleZ3aSc2h7TnFOhDXydZiK8D4mA0nbde0UY4-HmZHQ41rSGrwyW2oPr8oddmiG6fy7Ewc4tVS3IZMNcIQ6kI0UuT1uDXrWHrFCaoNSdmPPkTM2OmTxU_JYvtOAagS0u-u4GcxiB7ejE4tg8wytsyNrx__QhdsFx4jkds7p6zYPfjzfbEQYGPSfNkrLwRjySEftp8dXFV7cKDNJ_b-LJkywkJ-pJQRu1))

まず、ユーザBが管理権を持つ `original.git` を(`origin`という名前で)ローカルにcloneします:

```
git clone git@github.com:organization_x/original.git
cd forked
```

次に、取り込みたいリポジトリ `updated.git` を `user_a` という名前で追加します:

```
git remote add user_a git@github.com:user_a/updated.git
```

`user_a` の最新情報を取得します:

```
git fetch user_a
# あるいは、 git fetch --all で全リポジトリの情報を取得
```

`git branch -r` コマンドで `user_a`リポジトリを含んだブランチ名が見られるので、後は単一リモートリポジトリを扱う時と同じように操作してください。
例えば `user_a` の `master` ブランチを merge したいのなら次のような操作になります:

```
# user_a/master というブランチ名は git branch -r コマンドで確認できる
git merge user_a/master
```

ここでのキーポイントは `git remote` コマンドで複数のリモートリポジトリを取り扱う点ですので、"git remote add"といったフレーズでウェブ検索してみると理解が深まるかも知れません。

例えばGitHubのドキュメントだと、次に説明があります(残念ながらあまりわかり易くないので他を当たった方が良さそうですが):

- https://docs.github.com/ja/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories